# Switch or if elseif statement in success :function(data) ajax

Tags: php, ajax

```
$status = $row->status;  
switch ($status){
case "1":
$status = '<span class="badge badge-danger">Open</span> ';
break;
case "2":
$status=  '<span class="badge badge-secondary">On Hold</span> ';
break;
case "3":
$status= '<span class="badge badge-success">In Progress</span> ';
break;
case "4":
$status= '<span class="badge badge-info">Closed</span> ';
break;
}
```

This is my switch statement in my php code ; How do i do the same insite ajax success : function(data)

This is my ajax function

```
success: function(response){
      //console.log(response);
      $('.sub').html(response.sub);
      $('.msg').html(response.msg);
     //value = $(this).val(response.status); //Get the value from db;
     // if elseif or swithch statetment here//
      $('.sts').html('<span class="badge badge-danger">Open</span>'); //post it to html div;
    }
```

What can be done ?? is there any way to do it here or do i have to do it before encoding json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use switch case just like you use it in your php code like so:

```
    success: function(response){
      //console.log(response);
     $('.sub').html(response.sub);
     $('.msg').html(response.msg);
     var status = response.status; //Get the value from db;
    // if elseif or swithch statetment here//

    switch (status) {
        case "1":
            $('.sts').html('<span class="badge badge-danger">Open</span>');
            break;
        case "2":
            $('.sts').html('<span class="badge badge-secondary">On Hold</span>');
            break;
         case "3":
            $('.sts').html('<span class="badge badge-success">In Progress</span>');
            break;
         case "4":
            $('.sts').html('<span class="badge badge-info">Closed</span> ');
            break;

        default:
            $('.sts').html('<span class="badge badge-danger">Open</span>');
    }

}
```